# create session for variable and also want to unset it

Tags: codeigniter, session

i am using codeigniter i want to take variable in session below my controller function where i am creating session

```
function studios()
{

     $studio = $_POST['studio'];
     log_message('error', 'collected trainer type name is ' . $studio);
     if($studio)
     {
        $this->session->set_userdata('studio', $studio);
     }

 }
```

after creating this i am using session variable like this in another function

```
function fun_name(){  
$studio1 = $this->session->userdata('studio');
$data['quies']= $this->Welcome_model->selectedquestion($studio1);
$this->session->unset_userdata('studio');}
```

now problem is, i am getting first value in variable if variable value is changed .

Comment: I am not properly understand what you want?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am creating session for variable $studio = $_POST['studio'];  , but after unset session $this->session->unset_userdata('studio')  i am getting same value (previous value after change variable) in session

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update your session variable when you change it in database simultaneously. Otherwise you'll get previously stored value in session.

Comment: $this->session->unset_userdata('studio');
$this->session->set_userdata('studio',$studio1); i updated session like this, is it correct or wrong

Comment: It's correct but you need to sure that your $studio1 variable is not null.

Comment: still facing same problem....need page refresh to store new session value